# Apache HttpClient threading

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

I'm using Apache HttpClient 4.3.6 and I'm having a hard time with it in one particular instance.

Normally, all of my HttpPost calls are in a single main thread and happen serially. However, there's one instance where once a particular type of HttpPost happens, I need to start a side thread to monitor it. This side thread periodically tries to connect to the server to see if it's still up. If the connection to the server drops, I need to abort() the connection back in main so that it doesn't just get stuck until the timeout happens (I can legitimately have an operation where it's possible to take 45 minutes to complete).

I set up a PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager and a CloseableHttpClient at the beginning of main, and then I have a send method that main and the side thread both use to set up HttpPost objects that are local to the method. However, the client.execute(httpPost) local variable result from the side thread instance of the send method is somehow getting assigned to the local variable result in the main thread instance of the send method. They're getting crossed. I've searched around for the last few hours and I haven't found any solutions to this.

EDIT: Added example code. Had to obfuscated company stuff by changing various things to basic variables where classes would be used, so forgive some typos/whatever during that.

Class variables:

```
CloseableHttpClient client;
HttpPost longHttpPost;
boolean diePlz = false;
```

In main:

```
clientPool = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
clientPool.setMaxTotal(20);
clientPool.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
client = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(clientPool).build();
//Lots of logic here to set up things to be 'send()'ed
```

Send method:

```
private String send(String message, boolean longCall){
    RequestConfig.Builder requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom();
    requestConfig.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    String url = "http://" + ip + ":" + port + "/connector";
    HttpPost httpPost;
    if(longCall){
        httpPost = longHttpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    } else {
        httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    }
    httpPost.setConfig(requestConfig.build());
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    httpPost.setHeader("charset", "UTF-8");
    httpPost.setEntity(getEntity(message)); //getEntity() is a local method that overrides AbstractHttpEntity
    try {
        if(longCall && !threadRunning){
            diePlz = false;
            ConnectionCheck watcher = new ConnectionCheck();
            watcher.start();
        }
         //httpReponse is what seems to get crossed between invocations of send()
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(longCall ? longHttpPost : httpPost);
        //more stuff here to work with response
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e, e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        if(longCall){
            longHttpPost.releaseConnection();
        } else {
            httpPost.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

Nested thread class inside main class:

```
private class ConnectionCheck extends Thread implements Runnable, Serializable {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        threadRunning = true;
        try{Thread.sleep(5000);}catch(Exception e){LOG.error(e, e);}
        boolean registerReturn = register(false); //this calls send()
        if(registerReturn){
            String response = checkStatus(); //this calls send()
            if(response == null){ //if the connection we're watching drops...
                if(longHttpPost != null){
                    longHttpPost.abort(); //...then kill it
                }
            } else {
                while(response != null && !diePlz){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        LOG.error(e, e);
                        register(true);
                        threadRunning = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    response = checkStatus();
                    if(response == null){
                        if(longHttpPost != null){
                            longHttpPost.abort();
                        }
                    }
                }
                register(true); //this calls send()
                threadRunning = false;
            }
        } else {
            register(true); //this calls send()
            threadRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HTTP is designed as a stateless protocol, why don't you try websocket

Comment: Could you post some example of what you are doing code wise?

Comment: Added example code.